# Parsing JSON out of order Typescript

Tags: typescript

1. When i parse the code the console log shows me out of order, someone knows how to do it?
2. The numTipoEvento is inside tipoEvento, but the parser reads first inside the tipoEvento on the type date this not happens, like shows above:
   eventos-edit.component.ts:158 key => numTipoEvento é um number value => 3
   eventos-edit.component.ts:156 key => descricao is a string value => VENCIMENTO (RESGATE)
   eventos-edit.component.ts:161 key => tipoEvento is a object value => [object Object]
   eventos-edit.component.ts:162 {"numTipoEvento":3,"descricao":"VENCIMENTO (RESGATE)"}

```
    example output printed

    key => numEvento é um number value => 23
    eventos-edit.component.ts:161 key => date é um object value => [object Object]
    eventos-edit.component.ts:162 {"year":2022,"month":5,"day":14}
    eventos-edit.component.ts:163 false
    eventos-edit.component.ts:161 key => date é um object value => [object Object]
    eventos-edit.component.ts:162 {"year":2022,"month":5,"day":14}
    eventos-edit.component.ts:163 false
    eventos-edit.component.ts:161 key => date é um object value => [object Object]
    eventos-edit.component.ts:162 {"year":2022,"month":5,"day":14}
    eventos-edit.component.ts:163 false
    eventos-edit.component.ts:156 key => tipoIf é uma string value => CDB
    eventos-edit.component.ts:156 key => codigoIf é uma string value => CDB120014M7
    eventos-edit.component.ts:158 key => numTipoEvento é um number value => 3
    eventos-edit.component.ts:156 key => descricao is a string value => VENCIMENTO (RESGATE)
    eventos-edit.component.ts:161 key => tipoEvento is a object value => [object Object]
    eventos-edit.component.ts:162 {"numTipoEvento":3,"descricao":"VENCIMENTO (RESGATE)"}
    eventos-edit.component.ts:163 false
    eventos-edit.component.ts:158 key => taxa é um number value => 0
    eventos-edit.component.ts:158 key => pu é um number value => 0
    eventos-edit.component.ts:158 key => puJurosSobreAmortizacao é um number value => 0
    eventos-edit.component.ts:158 key => valorResidualUnitario é um number value => 0
    eventos-edit.component.ts:156 key => registradorOuEmissor é uma string value => MAXIMABC
    eventos-edit.component.ts:156 key => agentePagamento é uma string value => MAXIMABC

    example code:


        var obj = {
                numEvento: 23,
                dataEfetivacao:
                {
                  isRange:false,
                  singleDate: {
                    date: {
                      year: 2022,
                      month: 5,
                      day: 14
                    }
                  }
                },
                dataOriginal:
                {
                  isRange:false,
                  singleDate: {
                    date: {
                      year: 2022,
                      month: 5,
                      day: 14
                    }
                  }
                },
                dataLiquidacao:
                {
                  isRange:false,
                  singleDate: {
                    date: {
                      year: 2022,
                      month: 5,
                      day: 14
                    }
                  }
                }
                ,
                tipoIf: 'XXX',
                codigoIf: 'AAAAAAAAAAA',
                tipoEvento: { numTipoEvento: 3, descricao: 'TEXTO' },
                incorporaJuros: false,
                taxa: 0,
                pu: 0,
                puJurosSobreAmortizacao: 0,
                valorResidualUnitario: 0,
                registradorOuEmissor: 'TESTE',
                agentePagamento: 'TESTE'
              } 

     parseAll(obj){
      JSON.parse(obj,(key,value) => {
          if(typeof value === 'string'){
            console.log('key => ' + key + ' é uma string' + ' value => ' + value);
          }else if(typeof value === 'number' && (key !== 'year' && key !== 'month' && key !== 'day')){
            console.log('key => ' + key + ' é um number' + ' value => ' + value);
          }
          else if(typeof value === 'object' && (key === 'date' || key === 'tipoEvento')){
            console.log('key => ' + key + ' é um object' + ' value => ' + value);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
            console.log(value.hasOwnProperty(key));
           }

          return value;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. with this code i could keep the order of the json.

```
parseAll(obj) {
    let parentArray = [];
    const keys = Object.keys( this.eventos);
    console.log('tamenho'+ keys.length);
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      const linha = JSON.stringify(this.eventos[key]);
      const linhakeys = Object.keys(JSON.parse(linha));
      let childrenArray = [];
      linhakeys.forEach((keyAux) => {
        console.log('keyAux => ' + keyAux);
        console.log('valor' + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(linha)[keyAux]));
        if(JSON.parse(linha)[keyAux].hasOwnProperty('singleDate')){
          console.log('tem propriedade? ' + true);
        }else if(JSON.parse(linha)[keyAux].hasOwnProperty('numTipoEvento') && JSON.parse(linha)[keyAux].hasOwnProperty('descricao') ){
          console.log('tem propriedade? ' + true);
        }
        childrenArray.push(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(linha)[keyAux]));
      });
      parentArray.push(childrenArray);
    });
    console.log(parentArray);
  }
```